# Min/Max of a range VBA

Tags: excel, vba, max, min

I have a set of data that has blanks in between Them.

```
A1
1
2  

3 

4
5
6
```

I want to find the Min and max of each set of Numbers Between blanks. I know the formula but I don't know how to apply it to the row count of each range.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit in your attempt? SO is not a code writing service, you will receive better responses with the code in the question.

Comment: I don't have a code currently. Listing the numbers this way was the only way to get them on top of each other as an example of what the data looks like. I don't know how to create the code I need.

Comment: @BrandonCampbell assuming your data always starts at the top like you showed `.UsedRange.Rows.Count` for the sheet will get you the last row with data in it. Then just loop through the column from row 2 to that row and every time you run into a blank you'll have the range you can use the formula on. Remember to track the starting row of the range in a separate variable from the loop counter.

Comment: or put this formula in B1, Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter to exit edit mode and copy down: `=IF(A2="",MIN(INDEX(A:A,IFERROR(MATCH(2,INDEX(1/(A$1:A1=""),))+1,1)):A1),"")`  Change the `MIN` to `MAX` and put the in C1, CSE, copy down.

Comment: This is very helpful. thank you all!